# Sign in with Apple: how to group multiple apps under different developer accounts?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, apple-sign-in

My company publishes multiple white label iOS apps from different developer accounts, and I'm in the process of implementing Sign in with Apple. On the developer portal I can see that it is possible to group multiple apps under the same developer account, however our scenario is slightly different as we use multiple developer accounts.
To clarify, all these apps connect to same platform, and users are expected to hold a single account that can be used across all of them.
Is there a way to use the same Sign in With Apple in both apps?

Answer (score 2):

Just to update whoever may concern,
eventually the only solution was to move all application to the same developer account. we did the account immigration process and the sign in with apple works well on both applications.